# Replacing light and fan switches with a dual Lutron Caseta setup

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I have two switches on my wall: one that turns the ceiling fan light on/off, and one that turns the fan itself on/off. I would like to change this to a Lutron Caseta setup where I can dim the lights and control the speed of the fan. The fan is a pull-chain fan with speed settings High, Medium, Low, and Off.

Wiring this seems a bit trickier than the other light switches. How would I go about converting my existing setup to this new one? I've attached photos of the existing wiring and of the desired layout.

The electrical box also contains ground and neutral connections. I'm planning to expand it to a two-gang electrical box to fit the new setup.

Here are the part numbers for the two Lutron switches I purchased. Will these work for my setup?

1. Fan controller: PD-FSQN-WH
2. Light controller: PD-6WCL-WH

My existing setup is here:
[image: Existing switches]
[image: Existing wiring photo 1]
[image: Existing wiring photo 2]

The desired setup will hopefully look like this:
[image: The desired setup]

Thank you for any help you can give me!

EDIT: Alternatively, if this setup doesn't work, what's my best option for wiring a light dimmer with a simple on/off switch for the fan?

Comment: I take it expanding the existing wallbox out to two-gang isn't an issue for you?

Comment: @JACK oh yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single red wire going to the side of the old switch with the tab between the two screws is your always hot wire. It needs to be connected to the "Line/hot" black wire of each new switch.

Determine which of the two wires from the old switch control the fan and connect it to the yellow wire from your new fan switch. You will also have to connect the white wire from your new switch to the neutral and also connect your ground wire.

[image]

Take the remaining wire from your old switch and connect it to the other black wire from your new light switch and connect your grounds. This switch doesn't need a neutral connection.

[image]